# I am getting a BAD_ACCESS in my for in loop

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have the following block of code

```
-(void) spawnEnemies:(ccTime)dt
{

    static float lastSpawn;
    lastSpawn += dt;

    if (lastSpawn > 0.75) {
        for (NSDictionary *enemyData in levelData.enemies) {
            if ([[enemyData valueForKey:@"spawnCount"] intValue] < [[enemyData valueForKey:@"quantity"] intValue]) {
                // reset spawn timer
                lastSpawn = 0;

                // init enemy
                id enemy = [NSClassFromString([enemyData valueForKey:@"className"]) enemyInit];
                [enemy startAnimating];
                [enemy setSpawnPosition];
                [enemy moveToSpriteInit:playerSprite];
                [self addChild:enemy];
                [enemy release];

                NSNumber *spawnCount = [enemyData valueForKey:@"spawnCount"];
                [enemyData setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:([spawnCount intValue] + 1)] forKey:@"spawnCount"];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to know why this line:

```
[enemyData setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:([spawnCount intValue] + 1)] forKey:@"spawnCount"];
```

Is throwing a bad access error? I am trying to update the spawn count for each enemy each iteration. Do I need to make a rebuild the levelData.enemies array within the for loop and reassign the new one with the updated spawn count values to levelData.enemies once the for loop is completed?

Comment: Would help to know more about the class in which this method is defined, including the class's .h `@interface`, etc. Also, what are the implementation details of the `addChild:` method?

Comment: It's a cocos2d layer class / CCLayer

Comment: I'm pretty sure the bad access is from value reassignment on the iterated object in a for loop, I just need to know that's it for sure. It doesn't happen if I comment out the specific line I stated.

Comment: Could the previous line be setting `spawnCount` to a null pointer?

Comment: No it's not, if I nslog it, it has a value.

Answer (score 0):

I'm dumb, I just realized I did not update the for loop object type from NSDictionary to NSMutableDictionary, can't change values in an NSDict, duh!